# Fernet symmetric-key encryption

Tags: symmetric, implementation

### Fernet symmetric-key encryption

To encrypt and provide data — e.g. JSON strings in a database — using Python I'm wondering what is a good approach (package) for symmetric-key encryption.

The Python standard modules are only about hashes and secure random numbers: https://docs.python.org/3/library/crypto.html, so I started with https://github.com/pyca/cryptography as https://github.com/pycrypto/pycrypto looks rather stalled.
Former refers to **Fernet**, but strangely I cannot find a Wikipedia entry, neither much background nor 3rd-party investigation on it (see also https://github.com/fernet/spec/ and https://cryptography.io/).

Given the key is exchanged securely

- Is there an issue with the https://github.com/pyca/cryptography **Fernet** implementation?
- Is there further reading (*maybe under another name* than 'Fernet') that supports, it is fine data-security wise?

Comment: NaCL and [Python API of it](https://github.com/pyca/pynacl). Use 256-bit key.

Comment: Thank you!
After your hint I also found their reference https://cryptography.io/en/latest/faq/#how-does-cryptography-compare-to-nacl-networking-and-cryptography-library.
If you'd put your comment as answer, I'd accept it, since https://doc.libsodium.org/ looks better documented (...and has more GitHub stars, but I do not see a reason to argue against https://cryptography.io).

Comment: NaCL [core team](http://nacl.cr.yp.to/index.html) includes  Bernstein. My comment can't be an answer since you were asking about issues with the Fernet. See the [features](http://nacl.cr.yp.to/features.html) of their page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not sure where the name Fernet encryption comes from, but their [spec](https://github.com/fernet/spec/blob/master/Spec.md) indicates that they are using [AES-128](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) in [CBC mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_block_chaining_(CBC)) and then authenticating the cipher text with a [SHA256 HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC). They then base64 encode everything so that the cryptogram is printable ASCII.

I won’t claim to have done a code review, but their starting point is using good cryptographic primitives in a sensible way.

Comment: This is not exactly the answer I expected security-wise, but together with @kelalaka's comments above, and the usage (dependent packages) comparison of both libs
 [pyca/cryptography](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/network/dependents) vs.
 [libsodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/network/dependents)
 I feel safe enough now.